# How to prevent WiX from removing registry keys on patching

Tags: windows, wix, installation, patch

I am making a patch using the "WiX only" method.  That is:

`torch -p -xi Old.wixout New.wixout -out Differences.wixmst`

`pyro Patch.wixmsp -t MyPatch Differences.wixmst -out Patch.msp`

We write a product key to the registry when we initially install the product.  The user is prompted, as part of the installation, to enter this product key.

When we run the patch, it works fine but removes the product key from the registry.  All other installed registry keys remain; it is only the key that is added as part of the initial install that is removed.

Is there any way to create the patch in a way that doesn't remove this registry key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be 100% sure, but it sounds like you have probably made a change in the same feature as the registry key. I believe that this will cause Windows Installer to 'repair' the whole feature, and as a part of that it has decided to remove the registry key.